# Angular Service is returning data but not showing in HTML page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to AngularJS and I'm practicing with custom services. The following service is returning data, I checked it with an alert box, but data are not showing on page.

My HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Service Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/app/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app1">
    <form ng-controller="ServiceController">
      <input ng-model="a" />    
      <input type="button"  ng-click="getData()" value ="Show"> 
      <br />

      Square: <span ng-model="Square"></span>  <br />
      Cube: <span ng-model="Cube"></span>
    </form>
  </body>
```

My app.js file:

```
app = angular.module("app1", [])
.service('NumberService', function () {
  this.square= function(a){return a*a; };
  this.cube = function(a){return  a * a * a; };
})

.controller('ServiceController', ['$scope','NumberService',

function ($scope, NumberService) {

  $scope.getData = function () {
    //  alert('Button clicked' );

    var n = $scope.a;        
    $scope.Square = NumberService.square(n);
    alert($scope.Square);
    $scope.Cube = NumberService.cube(n);
  }
 }
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace `ng-model` with `ng-bind` here. ng-modal is for two way binding. Hence It will not work here.

```
Square: <span ng-model="Square"></span>  <br />
    Cube: <span ng-model="Cube"></span>
```

To

```
Square: <span ng-bind="Square"></span>  <br />
    Cube: <span ng-bind="Cube"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks Ved. It works and even {{Square}} also working.